# Are hyperlinks broken in Texifier using TexpadTeX as typesetter?

Tags: hyperref, urls, bugs, texpad

I don't seem to be able to typeset hyperlinks correctly using Texifier (formerly Texpad) with TexpadTeX as Typesetter.

The following MWE reproduces the behaviour:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
 
\begin{document}
............................................................................................ \url{https://www.google.com}
\end{document}
```

The problematic part is that texifier + TexpadTeX renders the page as containing this (note the two links):

> [................................................................................](https://www.google.com) [https://www.google.](https://www.google)
> com

while texifier + TeX Live produces the following result:

> ................................................................................ [https://www.google.](https://www.google.com)
> [com](https://www.google.com)

Note that the second link in the TexpadTeX result links to the url https://www.google without a trailing dot, which is consistent with only using the url package in the same situation, which might indicate that the second link was produced by the url package and the first link (on the dots) was produced by hyperref.

Is the support for hyperref simply broken currently, or is there something that I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

The full log of texifier + TexpadTeX is this:

```latex
This is TexpadTeX (based on TeX Version 3.14159265 with e-TeX extensions) running in extended mode embedded in Texpad 760 (preloaded format=latex 2021.3.29)  5 JUL 2023 17:43
**
(mwebrokenurl.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.16> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hypertext links for LaTeX
(hobsub-hyperref.sty
Package: hobsub-hyperref 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
(hobsub-generic.sty
Package: hobsub-generic 2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
Package: hobsub 2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
Package: infwarerr 2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
Package: ltxcmds 2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
Package: ifluatex 2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package: ifvtex 2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
Package: intcalc 2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
Package: ifpdf 2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
Package: etexcmds 2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
Package: kvsetkeys 2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
Package: kvdefinekeys 2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
Package: pdftexcmds 2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: pdfTeX >= 1.30 not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is not available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is not available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode not found.
Package: pdfescape 2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
Package: bigintcalc 2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
Package: bitset 2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
Package: uniquecounter 2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package hobsub Info: Skipping package `hobsub' (already loaded).
Package: letltxmacro 2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
Package: hopatch 2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
Package: xcolor-patch 2016/05/16 xcolor patch
Package: atveryend 2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
Package atveryend Info: \enddocument detected (standard20110627).
Package: atbegshi 2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
Package: refcount 2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
Package: hycolor 2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
) (ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
) (auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen103
\Hy@linkcounter=\count87
\Hy@pagecounter=\count88
(pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count89
(hyperref.cfg
File: hyperref.cfg TexpadTeX hyperref override
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4512.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4517.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4520.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4527.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4532.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4766.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5119.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen104
\Fld@menulength=\count91
\Field@Width=\dimen105
\Fld@charsize=\dimen106
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6373.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6378.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6381.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6388.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6393.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6398.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6403.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6443.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6447.
\Hy@abspage=\count92
\c@Item=\count93
\c@Hfootnote=\count94
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (default): htexpadtex.
(htexpadtex.def
File: htexpadtex.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref driver for TexpadTeX
(pdfmark.def
File: pdfmark.def 2018/02/06 v6.86b Hyperref definitions for pdfmark specials
\pdf@docset=\toks15
\pdf@box=\box26
\pdf@toks=\toks16
\pdf@defaulttoks=\toks17
\HyField@AnnotCount=\count95
\Fld@listcount=\count96
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count97
(rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: Feature \pdfmdfivesum is not available
(rerunfilecheck)             (e.g. pdfTeX or LuaTeX with package `pdftexcmds').
(rerunfilecheck)             Therefore file contents cannot be checked efficiently
(rerunfilecheck)             and the loading of the package is aborted.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip43
)) (mwebrokenurl.aux)
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box27
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 7.
(nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
(gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count98
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 7.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 7.
(mwebrokenurl.out) (mwebrokenurl.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 9.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `BeforeClearDocument' on input line 11.
[1

]
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AfterLastShipout' on input line 11.
(mwebrokenurl.aux)
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryEndDocument' on input line 11.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input line 11.
Package atveryend Info: Empty hook `AtVeryVeryEnd' on input line 11.
 )
```

And the full log of texifier + TeX Live is this:

```latex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2023.7.4)  5 JUL 2023 23:12
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**mwebrokenurl.tex
(./mwebrokenurl.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22> (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@section=\count186
\c@subsection=\count187
\c@subsubsection=\count188
\c@paragraph=\count189
\c@subparagraph=\count190
\c@figure=\count191
\c@table=\count192
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hypertext links for LaTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2022-10-05 v1.19 Key value parser (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2022-05-17 v2.50 Cross-referencing by name of section
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2022-06-15 v3.15 Key value format for package options (HO)
))
\c@section@level=\count193
)
\@linkdim=\dimen141
\Hy@linkcounter=\count194
\Hy@pagecounter=\count195
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count196
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4177.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4182.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4185.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4192.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4197.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4425.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count197
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 4763.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen142
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count198
\Field@Width=\dimen143
\Fld@charsize=\dimen144
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6042.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6047.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6050.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6057.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 6062.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6067.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6072.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2021/01/10 v1.0c Emulation of the original atbegshi
package with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count199
\c@Item=\count266
\c@Hfootnote=\count267
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend package
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count268
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count269
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2022-07-10 v1.10 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
 (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 285.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip50
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2023-01-16 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count270
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box51
) (/Users/username/Documents/Texifier/mwebrokenurl/.texpadtmp/mwebrokenurl.aux)
\openout1 = `mwebrokenurl.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 7.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 7.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring OFF on input line 7.
 (/Users/username/Documents/Texifier/mwebrokenurl/.texpadtmp/mwebrokenurl.out) (/Users/username/Documents/Texifier/mwebrokenurl/.texpadtmp/mwebrokenurl.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `mwebrokenurl.out'.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <7> on input line 10.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <5> on input line 10.
 [1

{/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/username/Documents/Texifier/mwebrokenurl/.texpadtmp/mwebrokenurl.aux)
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `mwebrokenurl.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7261 strings out of 476025
 117207 string characters out of 5790018
 1850388 words of memory out of 5000000
 27680 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 512455 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 75i,5n,76p,238b,427s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on /Users/username/Documents/Texifier/mwebrokenurl/.texpadtmp/mwebrokenurl.pdf (1 page, 23365 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 25 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 17 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 2 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: texpadtex run uses an old hyperref with a custom driver (htexpadtex.def) and a custom engine. It is not possible to debug this. Ask their support.